# After maximizing the form, half of the windows is lost and are out of windows for some screens

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

So here is my form onstartUp event code:

```
        int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Size = new Size(width, height);
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

the code works fine and the form starts up maximized. After distributing the applications to the user. A user complained and sent a screen shot with the form buttons on the RHS not appearing on the screen!!!

I figured what the problem is, but i don't know how to fix it. The problem is with windows fonts, Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\ font size on the development machine is small, on the customers it's medium.

how to accommodate for this in code?

Comment: Solution: trash winforms. It doesn't support multiple resolutions. use WPF, which has a much higher level of resolution independence.

Comment: I changed my font to 120% now i cant get the controls back to their original size

Comment: WinForms supports multiple resolutions just fine. You just have to know how to use the support. As AbZy advises, investigate the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties of controls.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is with windows fonts

Not exactly.  It is not the font size you are changing, it is the video adapter's dots-per-inch (DPI) setting.  The legacy setting is 96 dpi, since Vista it got a lot easier to change this setting.  Common other choices are 120 dpi (125%) and 144 dpi (150%), they are directly accessible from the Display applet with a radio button.

Monitor resolutions have been stuck for a very long time, ducking Moore's Law for a good 30 years already.  That's finally changing, in no small part due to Apple's push for "retina" displays.  The latest MacBook Pro has 2560 x 1600 pixels on a 13 inch screen, about 230 dpi.

That does come with a problem, any program that creates a, say, 1024x768 window has its UI turned into a postage stamp on such a display.  The UI just becomes unusable without a magnifying glass.  What is needed is for such a program to become aware of the video DPI setting and create a *larger* window, proportionally larger by the increase of the DPI setting compared to the way the window was originally designed.

This is automatic both in WPF and in Winforms.  WPF gets it by default since all of its locations and sizes are expressed in inches, with a unit of 1/96".  Winforms still works with pixels, but it has automatic scaling built-in through its AutoScaleMode property.

Which is what is happening on that user's machine, he's got the video DPI setting at a larger value than your machine.  However, without also having a larger number of pixels available on his screen.  Somewhat typically picked by someone that has a vision impairment, a side-effect of increasing the DPI setting is that fonts get larger and thus easier to read.  But with the inevitable problem that any controls that you put near the right and bottom edge of your window are going to fall off, the screen just isn't big enough.

You address this kind of problem by making your window layout adjustable.  Or in other words, by making your UI design work with any window size.  A very common feature of Windows programs.  Just try it on Visual Studio.  Drag the bottom right window corner around and observe how it deals with having less space available but still staying usable.  Lots of Winforms features to help you doing this, like the Control.Anchor and Dock properties, FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel controls, the Resize event for tough cases.

The Q&D fix for this is the Form.AutoScroll property.  Set it to True to permit the UI to still be usable, the scrollbars allows the user to still get to controls that are off the window.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has nothing to do with the problem. You designed the form in a higher screen resolution than the screen resolution of the user and didn't consider docking/anchoring the controls inside the form.